# Handling Access Violation Exceptions in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, buffer-overflow

Is there any way to handle an access violation exception in assembly language?

```
.start:
 MOV EAX,[0x400000]
 MOV DWORD [EAX],0x00
 JMP .start
```

Such a code exists, and the value of 0x400000 is the virtual memory retrieved by one thread. The memory area is then released by VirtualFree at random times by one threads.

If VirtualFree is performed at exactly the same time as MOV is being performed, an access violation will occur.
Is there any way to avoid or detect this?

Since the code is executed using an arbitrary code execution bug caused by overflow, modification of the source program is not allowed.

PS. The environment is windows 10 x86.

Comment: `MOV DWORD PTR [EAX],0x00000000` isn't NASM syntax.  PTR isn't a NASM keyword.  Are you sure you're assembling this with NASM?  I get `warning: 'PTR' is not a NASM keyword [-w+ptr]` / `error: symbol 'PTR' not defined`.  If you did define PTR somehow, that instruction might be assembling to some other addressing mode.  You want `mov dword [eax], 0`

Comment: The exception is handled at a higher privilege level by the OS, which may or may not provide a way to pass it along to user-level code (e.g. signals in Unix).  You haven't said what OS you are using, but generally, you would have to invoke the appropriate system call to install a handler.  That is probably more than you can reasonably do in shellcode.

Comment: There is probably some kind of lock or mutex inside the C library to synchronize calls to the memory allocation functions across threads.  You could reverse-engineer the library enough to find out where it is and how to manipulate it, and then take the lock yourself before doing your magic poke.

Comment: @PeterCordes
The ptr was mistakenly given by disassembly by the online assembler.
A simple mistake, sorry.

Comment: @NateEldredge
Sorry, I guess I didn't give you enough information.
The environment is windows 10 x86.